# MySQL Update disallowed header names?

Tags: mysql, sql-update

To save tearing any more of my hair out I thought I'd just pose the question here, as I'm having an infuriating time with PHP Mysql UPDATE: something I use quite a lot and thought I understood!

Basically, are there any table header names that are known to break MySQL update functions?  I have an Update mysql_query function that works perfectly, for example:

```
UPDATE table_name SET
part_number='000 - New Product',
product_code='1',
barcode_ref='1',
type='new type'
WHERE id='999'
```

However, if I include the table header called 'trigger' in the code it breaks it!

```
UPDATE table_name SET
part_number='000 - New Product',
trigger='YES',
product_code='1',
barcode_ref='1',
type='new type'
WHERE id='999'
```

The above sql returns an error of: `**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'trigger='YES', part_number='000 - New Product', product_code='1', barcod' at line 1**`

I have made an identical duplicate of the column called 'trigger' and re-named it 'testing_t' and immediately everything works perfectly as before.  I've tried both dumping my mysql_real_escape_string to variables for use in the UPDATE command and doing them inline, and even tried hard-coding the string and it still breaks.

Can anyone shed any light on this?  Ideally I'd really like to not have to change my table header name, as I don't want to modify the references to it across the site.  Obviously if there is no other option then I will, but I'm hoping I'm just being stupid and that someone can explain why it's happening/how to stop it happening!

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Comment: A trigger is a pl/sql block structure which is fired when a DML statements like Insert, Delete, Update is executed on a database table. A trigger is triggered automatically when an associated DML statement is executed. so ofcox you cant use field name trigger in your table , u need to change name of trigger coloumn

Comment: Use backtick character to escape MySQL table names and column names to avoid conflicts with reserved words. But also, it's generally a good idea to avoid using SQL reserved words for column names anyway, due to the potential confusion it may cause for you or another reader of your code at a later date.

Comment: Thanks for the responses both, I did think that may be the case.  I've tried escaping the column names but that just fails completely so I guess a rename is my only option!

Comment: Scratch that, I was using regular quotes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this query

```
UPDATE table_name SET
`part_number`='000 - New Product',
`trigger`='YES',
`product_code`='1',
`barcode_ref`='1',
`type`='new type'
WHERE id='999'
```

your query will fail because you have written `trigger` without ``` `` ```

`trigger` is reserved word in mysql for creating triggers.

To use reserved word as column name you have to write that word inside ``` `` ```

Answer (score 2):

`trigger` is a mySQL keyword.  If you enclose all column names in `` you will be safe.  It's good practice to not use these keywords as column names.

Other keywords are here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Comment: Thank you, are you sure that enclosing column names is a valid option though?  I think I'm going to rename the column and any references to it anyway, but I tried encapsulating each header name with '' and it failed.

Comment: @JoeP, you must use backward quotes ` `, not regular quotes.

Answer (score 1):

mySQL has a series of reserved words, of which TRIGGER is one. Consult this list of words as a guide for what NOT to call your columns/tables:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html